# Cypress Testing framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, unit-testing, cypress

I am new to testing within cypress and I am trying to test the code by automatic scheduler.

Is it possible to run an automatic scheduler process in the cypress testing framework?

Comment: Do you mean a trigger? Such as testing at a particular point such as after uploading a change?

Comment: Do you mean CICD process?

Comment: @GokulaKannanT Actually no. I have few test cases in cypress . I need to run those test cases by automatic. It's like cron job.

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere its like cron job.

Comment: @VenkatesanChandirasekar, I don't understand what kind of test cases we need to schedule?
Can you provide [simple minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Bitbucket you can put them in the pipelines.
For the configuration here is the [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html)

For example if you want to launch your tests directly during a merge you can do this:

```
pipelines:
    branches:
        develop: //your branche
            - step:
                name: Automatic test
                script:
                  - npm ci
                  - npm run cypress:run
```

Or with a custom pipeline that you run manually :

```
pipelines:
    custom:
         - step:
            name: Automatic test
              script:
                - npm ci
                - npm run cypress:run
```

And execute pipeline custom with button :
[image: Button pipeline custom]

Finally you can also run automatic pipelines on certain days at such times etc.

See :
[image: Schedule]

If to use github or another, you have several possibilities including this one see [here](https://github.com/marketplace/azure-pipelines)
You will be able to look at the documentation to help you understand how to configure your pipelines.